# replace a pipe delimited column using awk

Tags: shell, awk

I have a column seperated using pipe delimited , I have to replace the entire column with some other value .

Example :

A|B|C
I want to replace second column with "Z" as ,
A|Z|C

Comment: `awk -F'|' $2="Z" file`

Comment: I used this command , awk _F'|'  '{$2="string";print}' file_name , It is replacing , but it also replaces the pipe delimited with space

Comment: Thank you , i got an idea by using your command  , awk _F'|'  '{$2="string";print}' file_name > new_file_name

Answer (score 5):

Replacing the second field can be done by setting up the input and output field separators and simply changing the second field before printing:

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS = OFS = "|"} {$2 = "Z"; print}' inputFileName
```

as per the following transcript:

```
pax$ printf 'A|B|C\nD|E|F\n' | awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"}{$2="Z";print}'
A|Z|C
D|Z|F
```

Comment: I used this command , awk _F'|'  '{$2="string";print}' file_name , It is replacing , but it also replaces the pipe delimited with space

Comment: @Jim, so what you're saying is that you did something I _didn't_ suggest and it didn't work. And somehow that's my fault? Just kidding :-) The problem is that `-F` only sets the _input_ field separator, you want to set the _output_ one as well, hence the `BEGIN` block.

Comment: Actually i have  a pipedelimited file , i have to replace particular column with some string , how can i do that

Comment: @Jim, if it's complaining about `BIGIN`, you may want to spell it better :-) As per your most recent comment, I'm pretty certain that's what I've provided - it replaces the second column of a pipe-delimited file with the string `Z`. If that's _not_ what you want, you may need to explain more.

Comment: The thing is i have a pipe delimited file , i have to replace particular column with specific string , how can i do that ?

Comment: @Jim, the way you do it is the way I've shown, that transcript was copied directly from a terminal session. I think I know where the problem lies though and I'll take the responsibility for that. The first code block in my answer is meant to be an `awk` command, not something you type directly into the shell. I'll fix that up.

Comment: Ya i am directly executing in the terminal

Comment: @Jim, okay, the change should fix that.

Comment: Finally i got the command , awk -F'|'  '{$2="string";print}' file_name > new_file_name . Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Below command provided the expected solution,

```
awk -F'|' '{$2="string";print}' file_name > new_file_name
```

$2 --> denotes the second position of the delimiter, |

Comment: By redefining a field `$n`, you automatically rebuild the full record `$0`. For this, it will use the output field-separator `OFS` as a delimiter and not the field separator `FS`. Hence, the output here will be `$1 $2 $3` and not `$1|$2|$3` as `OFS` is by default is a single space. You also need to update `OFS`